# berks install found nothing to rewrite

Tags: ruby, windows, git, chef-infra, berkshelf

I am using a Windows 7 x64 computer, with ChefDK 0.3.0-1 installed, with the berkshelf, and omnibus gems installed as well. I setup my Berksfile and metadata.rb files as such

metadata.rb

```
depends 'users', '~> 1.7'
depends 'sudo', '~> 2.6'
```

Berksfile

```
cookbook 'users', git: 'https://github.com/sethvargo-cookbooks/users.git', rel: 'cookbooks/users', tag: 'v1.7.0'
cookbook 'sudo', git: 'https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/sudo.git', rel: 'cookbooks/sudo', tag: 'v2.6.0'
```

I set the environment variable in my System Environment Variables to:

```
BERKSHELF_PATH=C:/
```

However, when I issue the command:

```
> berks install
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\c\c\cookbook_test> berks install
Resolving cookbook dependencies...
Fetching 'addm_setup' from source at .
Fetching 'sudo' from https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/sudo.git (at v2.6.0/cookbooks/sudo)
Git error: command `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter "cookbooks/sudo" --force` failed. If this error persists, try removing the cache directory at 'C:/chef/.cache/git/6f5ef5c786d127e1b549253a13b5d48c181aedeb'.Output from the command:

Found nothing to rewrite
```

I figured out I can't use the Cygwin Git, either because I don't know what to configure for it or something, and that the Git from git-scm works so far. I'm also using Windows Command Prompt to execute these commands. I'm not sure what to do from here, or what this is trying to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, and fortunately, this was a simple answer. I was receiving the errors listed in the question because I had the

```rb
rel: 'cookbooks/sudo'
```

What that was doing was looking for a pre-existing repository, but that didn't exist. So, once I removed that, the cookbooks were downloaded and included for use.

The new results were:

```rb
C:\c\c\cookbook_test> berks install
Resolving cookbook dependencies...
Fetching 'cookbook_test' from source at .
Fetching 'sudo' from https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/sudo.git (at v2.6.0)
Fetching 'users' from https://github.com/sethvargo-cookbooks/users.git (at v1.7.0)
Fetching cookbook index from https://supermarket.getchef.com...
Using cookbook_test (0.1.0) from source at .
Using sudo (2.6.0) from https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/sudo.git (at v2.6.0)
Using users (1.7.0) from https://github.com/sethvargo-cookbooks/users.git (at v1.7.0)
```

Comment: Not quite, what that does is look for a subfolder in the git repository. As that isn't the case here, it isn't needed.